# Failed resolution of: [Lcom/google/android/gms/phenotype/ExperimentTokens, When i click on the place search bar

Tags: xamarin.android

`09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135): Process: com.demo.coltonline, PID: 27135
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Lcom/google/android/gms/phenotype/ExperimentTokens;
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.ClearcutLogger.<clinit>(Unknown Source:28)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.ClearcutLogger.anonymousLogger(Unknown Source:0)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.ds.a(PG:3)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fx.o(PG:36)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fx.p(PG:37)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fx.q(PG:42)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fx.a(PG:5)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places.a(PG:40)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fz.e(PG:22)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fz.g(PG:46)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fz.h(PG:50)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fz.k(PG:58)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fz.a(PG:2)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity.onCreate(PG:6)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.phenotype.ExperimentTokens" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.demo.coltonline-nAMq5vMmPTRPZ31mMmoxTQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.demo.coltonline-nAMq5vMmPTRPZ31mMmoxTQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.demo.coltonline-nAMq5vMmPTRPZ31mMmoxTQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    09-11 16:24:41.979 E/AndroidRuntime(27135):     ... 29 more`

**I have integrated places SDK ,
    Installed Xamarin.Google.Android.Places
    Xamarin.Android.Volley.1.1.1.1
    Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places   these packages but i am getting above error**

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved after uninstall and reinstalled the "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Phenotype" package in nuget packages.These kind of issue purely based on package installation or version mismatch problems. Make sure all packages installed properly. Sometimes it shows package was installed in the nuget package manager but it is absent or not refereed in the reference folder. We need to make sure that installed packages are present in reference folder if not we have to reinstall and check.